# All wallpapers are black in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background

I want to change the desktop background and before it changed, but it was not a problem, but I did not change this week, and whenever it turns out, you can help you guide?
sys: kubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Open your filebrowser and go to /usr/share/wallpapers. You will find subfolders (such as Autumn or Blue Curl). In those folders there is a file called metadata.desktop and another folder called 'contents'. In 'contents' you'll find a folder 'images' and a file called 'screenshot.jpg'. Check if the structure is like described. If it is not like described it will (probably) not show the images. Than search for e.g. 1920x1080.jpg, check it's path. In the screen you show click on 'add image', go to the path you discovered and add the image.